# Setting a default value for an NSManagedObject in SwiftUI Picker?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

I'm working with `Picker` in SwiftUI to choose from a list of Core Data `NSManagedObject`s, and can't get the picker to display a default value. It also won't set a new value after one is chosen. Is there a way to have a default value for the picker to display?

Here's where the properties for my NSManagedObject are set up.

```
extension Company {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Company> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Company>(entityName: "Company")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var companyContacts: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var companyRoles: NSSet?

    //...

}
```

And here's where I'm trying to use it.

```
struct AddRoleSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Company.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Company.name, ascending: true)
        ]
    ) var companies: FetchedResults<Company>

//...

@State var company: Company? = // Can I put something here? Would this solve my problem?

//...

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $company, label: Text("Company")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(companies, id: \.self) { company in
                            company.name.map(Text.init)
                        }
                    }
                }
                //...
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fetched results on View.init phase yet, so try the following

```
@State var company: Company? = nil   // << just initialize

//...

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $company, label: Text("Company")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(companies, id: \.self) { company in
                            company.name.map(Text.init)
                        }
                    }
                }
                //...
            }
        }
    }.onAppear {
       // here companies already fetched from database
       self.company = self.companies.first      // << assign any needed
    }
}
```